# Turning a Standard Javascript Confirm Dialog into Bootbox Confrim

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootbox

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#close").click(function () {
                var link = $(this).attr("href"); // "get" the intended link in a var
                var result = confirm("Are you sure?");
                if (result) {
                    document.location.href = link;  // if result, "set" the document location      
                }
            });
        });
```

How would I use Bootbox dialogs instead of the JavaScript Dialogs?

EDIT

Well I've tried but nothing happens upon clicking the Ok button the bootbox dialog

```
        $(document).on("click", "#close", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var link = $(this).attr("href"); // "get" the intended link in a var
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to close this Incident? This operation cannot be reversed.", function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        document.location.href = link;
                    } else {
                        console.log("user declined");
                    }
                });
        });
```

Comment: I get one error in my JS debugger and that is: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. even though im already using preventDefault :s

Comment: That isn't an error. And it isn't being caused by your code.

Comment: Place a console.log before the bootbox.confirm, does it get reached?

Comment: Ok did that. It does get reached yes

Comment: Are you sure you are using bootbox correctly? i've never used it before but it's the next logical step in this debugging process.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49187/discussion-between-aspcoder1450-and-kevin-b)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a Bootbox Dialog, like below.

Bootbox Dialogs allow you to attach callback functions to the buttons, so you can specify a specific function to occur for each button.

I also included the line `closeButton: false,` so that the user cannot click a close button to dismiss the Dialog, and instead must either click `Ok` or `Cancel`.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#close", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href"); // "get" the intended link in a var

    bootbox.dialog({
        closeButton: false,
        message: "Are you sure you want to close this Incident? This operation cannot be reversed.",
        buttons: {
            cancel:{
                label: "Cancel",
                callback: doThisOnCancel
            },
            ok:{
                label: "Ok",
                callback: doThisOnOk
            }
        }       
    });

    doThisOnCancel(){
        console.log("user declined");               
    }

    doThisOnOk(){
        document.location.href = link;
    }
});
```